# Infinitely bidirectionally scrollable containers in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, infinite-scroll

Is there a library for angular 6 that provides a way of creating a container that can be scrolled in 2 directions indefinitely?
The content of that container would have to be created dynamically in code.

Think of a number line for example, that would start at position 0 and could be scrolled indefinitely in the positive or negative direction.
I have included a simple example for demonstration purposes:

```css
ul {
  height: 5em;
  width: 10ch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>-20</li><li>-19</li><li>-18</li><li>-17</li><li>-16</li><li>-15</li><li>-14</li><li>-13</li><li>-12</li><li>-11</li><li>-10</li><li>-9</li><li>-8</li><li>-7</li><li>-6</li><li>-5</li><li>-4</li><li>-3</li><li>-2</li><li>-1</li><li>0</li><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ngx-infinite-scroll` is a pretty good library. Here's a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-infinite-scroll). Here's the [Npm package.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll)